# Sync app data from Android app to PC

Tags: android

My scenario: currently users of my app fill out some information, and when they are done press the SYNC button. This information is sent via json to an http webservice, where it gets stored online and saved - then a response is sent back to the mobile app and the data is cleared from the internal Sqlite database.

My problem: some users are in low/no coverage areas, without mobile reception or Wi-Fi. So in this case, when they SYNC nothing happens.

My solution: allow these users to connect their phone via USB to a computer with internet access. Then the users can open the app, press some new SYNC VIA PC button... maybe I can write a companion app in C# for the PC to save this data locally and sync it the http webservice.

**My question:** what would this process be called? I don't even know what terms to Google. Is what I am asking even possible? If so, from the Android perspective - how can I send json data across the USB cable into the computer? On the C# perspective, how can I pick up this transmission of data?

Any guidance would be great, thank you.

Comment: Please could you elaborate? It sounds like that would only help for syncing wirelessly to the cloud... which I can already do.